# How do you add an attribute to the html tag in SharePoint masterpages?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

I want to turn the following tag produced in SharePoint 2013 master pages:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

into the following:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" **xml:lang=”en”**>
```

It is controlled by the following:

```
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" 
                      ID="SPHtmlTag"
                      runat="server" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are out of luck as that control and the asp.net Control superclasses don't appear to give you an option to set/generate the xml:lang attribute.  You could convert:

```
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" 
                      ID="SPHtmlTag"
                      runat="server" >
```

to something like:

```
<html ID="SPHtmlTag" runat="server" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" >
```

but you'd be missing out on anything else that control was doing for you.